# Linq query which retrieved parent/child of children with a collection

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a self referencing `Category` class from which I would like to retrieve parent categories and all corresponding children if it has at least one child category and has at least 1 or more activities (`ICollection<Activity>`) in the collection.

This would also go for children of children as these should only be returned if there are children categories with at least 1 or more activities.

If there are no child categories with at least 1 or more activities the parent or child `Category` should *not* be returned.

The query should return the parent `Category` as an actual `Category` object and not just the `CategoryId`. It this possible?

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

The query which partially works:

```
 var categories = _db.Categories
        .Where(x => x.Parent != null &&  x.Activities.Count > 0)
        .GroupBy(x => x.ParentId)
        .Select(g => new { Parent = g.Key, Children = g.ToList() }).ToList();
```

Comment: where is your query that you have tried?

Comment: any particular reason you're storing the `ParentId`? wouldn't you just get this from `Parent.CategoryId`?

Comment: @RufusL That's typical in EF so that you can pull out a row as one entity without actually pulling out the referenced entities.  You get the id that links to the parent, but not the parent object.

Comment: What about a given instance where a parent has say, 4 child and only 1 satisfies the condition. Does selecting the parent implies that all the child will automatically be selected?

Comment: @P.K. How do you know one of the possibly many sub children satisfies the condition? And if so how do you know the parent back only ones? Do you have an example linq query?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start off a bit smaller, since the query you are looking to create is somewhat complex. We will create your query from the bottom up. First off, you want to eliminate categories that do not have any child categories with at least one or more activities. Let's make a `Predicate` to return `true` for those that should be included and `false` for those that should be excluded, at a single level. We will do this in two stages. First, let's make a predicate that returns `true` for categories that have activities:

```
Predicate<Category> hasActivities = cat => cat.Activities.Any();
```

Second, let's make a `Predicate` to return `true` for those categories with child categories that have activities:

```
Predicate<Category> hasChildWithActivities = 
    parentCat => parentCat.Children.Any(hasActivities);
```

Now let's create the filter query that will filter a given `Category`'s descendants. To do this, we will create a `Func` that takes a parent `Category`, performs the logic and returns the updated `Category`:

```
Func<Category, Category> getFilteredCategory =
    parentCat => 
    {
        parentCat.Children = parentCat.Children
            .Where(hasChildWithActivities)
            .Select(getFilteredCategory);

        return parentCat;
    });
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
Func<Category, Category> getFilteredCategory = delegate(Category parentCat)
{
    parentCat.Children = parentCat.Children
        .Where(hasChildWithActivities)
        .Select(getFilteredCategory);

    return parentCat;
};
```

In your OP, you mentioned that you wanted to filter parents as well. You can use this same logic on the parents by traversing up to the top level and running this query, or by creating a separate query with "joins" or more complex "select" statements. IMHO, the latter would likely be messy and I would advise against it. If you need to apply the logic to parents as well, then first traverse up the tree. Either way, this should give you a good start.

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck and happy coding! :)